# The fluctuations of a random path

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, percolation, ising-model

Suppose I have a $n \times n$ square grid and for each square, I assign 1 with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and 0 with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. On the boundary, I put 1s on the lower half and 0s on the upper half.

[image: Randomly assigned 0 and 1 in a square grid]

Now, I look at the boundaries between cells with zeros and ones:

[image: Boundaries between 0s and 1s]

Due to the parity constraints there is necessarily a path from the middle left to the middle right (in fact there are many paths).

Now, I am interested in the path from left to right that have the lowest amount of fluctuations as the size of the grid $n$ tends to infinity.

By a huge detour chain of reasoning I can prove that with high probability the path will not fluctuate too much as $n \to \infty$. But how can I see it directly in this picture?

Comment: what does fluctuate mean?

Comment: If we put the x-axis in the middel of the box one definition could be the largest (absolute value from x-axis) deviation of the path from left to right that has the smallest largest deviation. In the example this number is 5 which is acheived at the point in the bottom middle.